# Could not find `ReaderBuilder` in `csv`

Tags: csv, rust

Compiling this code:

```
extern crate csv;

fn main() {
    let mut test = csv::ReaderBuilder::new();
}
```

Results in:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Could not find `ReaderBuilder` in `csv`
 --> src/main.rs:5:25
  |
5 |     let mut test = csv::ReaderBuilder::new();
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Could not find `ReaderBuilder` in `csv`
```

The `Cargo.toml` file has the following dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
csv = "0.15.0"
rustc-serialize = "0.3.24"
```

Why is this happening (all examples use the `ReaderBuilder` in a similar manner: [example_1](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/blob/6f24780f26a81336bc919e4e2b07cdcadb0c309d/examples/cookbook-read-colon.rs) and [example_2](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/blob/6f24780f26a81336bc919e4e2b07cdcadb0c309d/examples/cookbook-read-colon.rs)).

Comment: What happens if you compile [example_1](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/blob/6f24780f26a81336bc919e4e2b07cdcadb0c309d/examples/cookbook-read-colon.rs)?

Comment: @BobJarvis Same error `src/main.rs:8:24`, `let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()`, `Could not find 'ReaderBuilder' in 'csv'`

Comment: How about the examples at [this page](https://crates.io/crates/csv)?

Comment: Why `csv = "0.15.0"`?

Comment: @trentcl That's the version specified on https://crates.io/crates/csv. I tried csv = "0.14.0" with same results.

Comment: @BobJarvis Compiling the projects on https://crates.io/crates/csv and anything with `Reader` only works. It's the `ReaderBuilder` that fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReaderBuilder` is only available in the csv 1.0 release, as indicated in the documentation. You are trying to use an older version.

Please consider following [the instructions in the documentation](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0/csv/#setup):

> Add this to your Cargo.toml:
>
> ```
> [dependencies]
> csv = "1"
> ```
>
> and this to your crate root:
>
> ```
> extern crate csv;
> ```